# Counter list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've written a program that pulls a random coordinate/color set from a list and draws a circle in a graphics window. I want it to *stop* drawing circles as soon as every coordinate/color set has been drawn at least once. I also want to document how many times each of the 9 possible coordinate/color sets were used. I've initialized a counter, `count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` that I want to print each time a new circle is drawn, appended with the number of times each state has been used. Tips on how to do this?

Example output in shell:

```
count = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
count = [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
count = [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
count = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
count = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Please and thank you in advance!

```
import random, turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.pensize(3)
alex.color("black")


def turtle_draw():
    '''draws a circle with given coordinates and in a
given color, prints a counter.'''

    color, place = random_state_finder()
    alex.pu()
    alex.goto(place)
    alex.shape("circle")
    alex.shapesize(3)
    alex.fillcolor(color)

    count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    wn.ontimer(turtle_draw, 250)

def random_state_finder():
    '''randomly generates a state number from 0 to 8
and assigns the state's data to color and place.'''

    rng = random.Random()
    state_num = rng.randrange(0, 8)

    L = [((-150, 150), "red"), ((0, 150), "orange"),
              ((150, 150), "yellow"), ((-150, 0), "green"),
              ((0, 0), "blue"), ((150, 0), "violet"),
              ((-150, -150), "cyan"), ((0, -150), "magenta"),
              ((-150, -150), "purple")]

    random_state = L[state_num]

    color = random_state[1]
    place = random_state[0]

    return color, place

turtle_draw()
```

Comment: For starters, you need to update `count` each time a state is chosen; to do that, it can't just be defined locally to `turtle_draw`.

Answer (score 0):

In some way's it's simpler than you're making it.  The key is `random.shuffle()` -- just mix up the states list once then walk through the shuffled list one by one.  The complication is your `count` list which means we actually make an index list into the states list and shuffle the index list, leaving the original states list untouched:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import shuffle

states = [((-150, 150), "red"), ((0, 150), "orange"), \
    ((150, 150), "yellow"), ((-150, 0), "green"), \
    ((0, 0), "blue"), ((150, 0), "violet"), \
    ((-150, -150), "cyan"), ((0, -150), "magenta"), \
    ((-150, -150), "purple")]

def turtle_draw():
    '''
    draws a circle with given coordinates
    and in a given color, prints a counter.
    '''

    index = indexes.pop()

    place, color = states[index]
    alex.goto(place)
    alex.fillcolor(color)

    counts[index] += 1
    print(counts)

    if indexes:
        screen.ontimer(turtle_draw, 250)

counts = [0 for state in states]

indexes = [i for i, state in enumerate(states)]  # could also use list(range(len(states)))

shuffle(indexes)

screen = Screen()

alex = Turtle(shape="circle", visible=False)
alex.shapesize(3)
alex.penup()
alex.color("white")  # don't want to see alex until first state
alex.showturtle()

turtle_draw()

screen.exitonclick()
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>
```